# Cocos2D - Weird warning when calling a method in another class

Tags: ios, methods, cocos2d-iphone, warnings

I have to classes, Survival and HUDLayer.
In my HUDLayer I have a SneakyButton and with that button I call a method in the Survival.m called -(void)fire but when I call the method I get the error message `CCSpriteBatchNode: resizing TextureAtlas capacity from`
and I know the method is being called since I check that with a NSLog()

```
-(void)fire {
NSLog(@"Fire");
}
```

And in my log it returns Fire as well as that weird warning.
When I get the warning, fps drop to around 30. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: messages in the log are not automatically errors, most are merely informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can find inside cocos2d sources about resizing texture atlas:

```
// if we're going beyond the current CCTextureAtlas's capacity,
// all the previously initialized sprites will need to redo their texture coords
// this is likely computationally expensive
```

[This is the explication](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/20821) of what is happening:

> The internal array of sprites are increasing because your are adding more sprites to the batch (the log is there just to let you know on debug versions).

Child nodes also count toward reaching the limit of capacity of the sprite.

You can try and set a higher limit for your batch node:

```
[CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"myAtlas.png" capacity:100]; // capacity for 100 objects
```

to reduce the frequency of this happening.

Comment: and you want to avoid this message because every reallocation costs time